# css visibility based on variable

Tags: html, css, sql

I'm running out of hair and hoping someone maybe able to help identify my problem with button visibility. I am sending out an email with shipping tracking information embedded in a button "Track Your FedEX Package" and "Track Your UPS Package". My problem is both buttons are visible. I only want the correct button visible based on the `@SHIP_VIA = UPS` or `FEDEX`. This is embedded in a SQL query.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
DECLARE @SHIP_VIA nvarchar(80)


'</table>



<br>


<div>

<! [if mso]>

<% if SHIP_VIA == FEDEX GROUND%>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=' + @TRACKING + '" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:300px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#d62828">

    <w:anchorlock/>

    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">

     Track Your FedEX Package

    </center>

  </v:roundrect>


<% else if SHIP_VIA == UPS GROUND%>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&tracknum=' + @TRACKING + '" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:300px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#d62828">

    <w:anchorlock/>

    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">

     Track Your UPS Package

    </center>

  </v:roundrect>


  <![endif]>



</div>'
```

[image: image of both buttons]

Comment: This seems like a matter of templating. What templating system are you using?

Comment: the template I manipulated was the following, I thought that if the viewer could decipher the viewer, I could use the same logic to determine a value. <![if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://google.com" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:300px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#d62828">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">
      Contact Axme
    </center>
  </v:roundrect

Comment: >
  <![endif]>
  <![if !mso]>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tr>
  <td align="center" width="300" height="40" bgcolor="#d62828" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; display: block;">
    <a href="http://google.com" style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family:sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block">
    <span style="color: #ffffff;">
      Contact Axme
    </span>
    </a>
  </td>
  </tr> </table>
  <![endif]>
</div>'

Comment: That's not a templating system, though, it's just a template. "MSO" checks to see if the code is being displayed in Microsoft Outlook, but that's not a templating system as such.

It looks like you might be using the EJS templating system, is that the case? The syntax you provided won't do anything in plain vanilla HTML/JS without a templating system that's listening, and then changing your code into something executable.

Comment: The system is BMS and is using SQL '16 report builder